# ¿Cual es la funcion de los testigos en una pipe?

Tags: c, linux

Veran es un ejercicio que he sacado de un libro, donde imprime los primeros 5 pares y luego los primeros 5 impares asi hasta llegar a 2000 usando una pipe llamada tuberia para compartir informacion entre los procesos,pero lo que no entiendo es que en las funciones generar pares, generar impares se imprime y se lee en 2 pipes una variable de tipo char llamada testigo que segun yo  solo tiene basura ya que no se le a asignado nada.

entiendo todo lo demas excepto el uso de esa variable en las 2 pipes extras, agradeceria su ayuda para entender el por que se uso las 2 pipes extras con una variable tipo char

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void GenerarPares(int tuberia, int t1, int t2);
void GenerarImpares(int tuberia, int t1, int t2);
void ConsumirNumeros(int tuberia);
void manejador();

int main(){
pid_t pid1, pid2;
int tuberia[2], t1[2], t2[2];

struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler = manejador;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&act.sa_mask,SIGINT);
act.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGKILL,&act,NULL);

//El proceso padre, que crea la tuberia, sera el proceso p1
if(pipe(tuberia) < 0){
    perror("No se puede crear la tuberia");
    exit(0);
}
if(pipe(t1) < 0){
    perror("No se puede crear la tuberia");
    exit(0);
}
if(pipe(t2) < 0){
    perror("No se puede crear la tuberia");
    exit(0);
}

//Se crea el proceso p2
switch(pid1=fork()){
    case -1:
        perror("Error al crear el proceso");
        //Se cierra la tuberia
        close(tuberia[0]);
        close(tuberia[1]);
        close(t1[0]); close(t1[1]);
        close(t2[0]); close(t2[0]);
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 0:
        //Proceso hijo, p2
        //Cierra el descriptor de lectura del pipe
        close(tuberia[0]);
        //ESte proceso lee de T1 y escribe en T2
        close(t1[1]);
        close(t2[0]);
        GenerarImpares(tuberia[1], t1[0], t2[1]);
        //EL proceso acaba cerrando los descriptores
        close(tuberia[1]);
        close(t1[0]);
        close(t2[1]);
    break;
    default:
        //El proceso padre crea al proceso P3
        switch(pid2 = fork()){
            case -1:
                perror("Error al crear el proceso");
                //Se cierra la tuberia
                close(tuberia[0]);
                close(tuberia[1]);
                close(t1[0]); close(t1[1]);
                close(t2[0]); close(t2[1]);
                kill(pid1, SIGKILL);
                exit(0);
                break;
            case 0:
                //Proceso hijo, p3
                //Cierra el descriptor de ESCRITURA del pipe
                close(tuberia[1]);
                close(t1[0]); close(t1[1]);
                close(t2[0]); close(t2[1]);
                ConsumirNumeros(tuberia[0]);
                close(tuberia[0]);
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                //Escribe en la tuberia
                close(tuberia[0]);
                //Cierra lo que no necesita
                close(t1[0]);
                close(t2[1]);   
                GenerarPares(tuberia[1],t1[1],t2[0]);
                //Proceso cierra los descriptores
                close(tuberia[1]);
                close(t1[1]);
                close(t2[0]);
        }   
}
}

void GenerarPares(int tuberia, int t1, int t2){
int i = 0, count=2;
char testigo;

while(count <= 2000){
//write(t1,&testigo,sizeof(char));
read(t2,&testigo,sizeof(char));
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    //Inserta el ssiguiente numero par
    write(tuberia,&count,sizeof(int));
    count= count + 2;
}
write(t1,&testigo,sizeof(char));
}
}

void GenerarImpares(int tuberia, int t1, int t2){
int i = 0, count= 1;
char testigo;
write(t2,&testigo,sizeof(char));
while(count <=1999){
read(t1, &testigo, sizeof(char));
//i es el numero impar que se genera
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    write(tuberia,&count,sizeof(int));
    count= count+2;
}
write(t2,&testigo,sizeof(char));
}
}

void ConsumirNumeros(int tuberia){
int i;
while(read(tuberia,&i,sizeof(int))>0){
    //Escribe el caracter
    printf("%d \n", i);
}
}

void manejador(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun funcionan las tuberias en C, estas 2 variables a las que haces referencia se denominan en la documentacion sobre tuberias como descriptores de ficheros que van a almacenar las partes de lectura uno de ellos y de escritura el otro, para definir el sentido de la tuberia dado que es una cola de tipo FIFO.

Texto en la documentacion:

> Para crear la tubería se emplea la función pipe(), que abre dos
>   descriptores de fichero y almacena su valor en los dos enteros que
>   contiene el array de descriptores de fichero. El primer descriptor de
>   fichero es abierto como O_RDONLY, es decir, sólo puede ser empleado
>   para lecturas. El segundo se abre como O_WRONLY, limitando su uso a la
>   escritura. De esta manera se asegura que el pipe sea de un solo
>   sentido: por un extremo se escribe y por el otro se lee, pero nunca al
>   revés. Ya hemos dicho que si se precisa una comunicación
>   “full-duplex”, será necesario crear dos tuberías para ello.

Articulo de ejemplo:
https://www.programacion.com.py/escritorio/c/pipes-en-c-linux